# Which package of GIMP source code contains the Scissor Selection tool (LiveWire)?

Tags: gimp

I am trying to write a program that allows the user to use the mouse to select an object of a photo by clicking points around the object.  My code should create a patch around the object and then copy a the enclosed region.  This functionality is exactly how the Scissor Selection tool of GIMP works.  I tried to download GIMP source code to see how this feature was implemented by GIMP developers.  However, there are so many packages and I could not find the source files that has the code for the Scissor Selection tool (LiveWire algorithm).  Does anyone know?

Comment: What exactly do you call "packages" - is it directories?

Answer (score 1):

Found it by searching the Github repo for "livewire":

https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/b3d2324527d9b805fa88dd2c8184030eaf4ac4bf/app/tools/gimpiscissorstool.c